# PHP: Count Number of Arrays in SESSION

Tags: php, arrays, session

I am storing shopping cart data in a SESSION Array like this:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$sessID] = array ('quantity' => 1, 'price' => $prodPrice, 'prodName' => $prodName, 'size' => $size, 'handle' => $handle)
```

Each time a user adds an item to the cart, a new sessID is created and a new Session Array.

How do I count how many sessID's there are when it comes to checkout?

I don;t want to count the items in the shopping cart - I want to count the number of occurances of $_SESSION['cart']

Thank you

Comment: If any of the answers here solved your problem, you should accept it by clicking on the check mark below the answers number of votes. Others will then know that this issue has been closed.

Answer (score 7):

If I understand the question correctly you're looking for [count()](http://docs.php.net/count)

```
count($_SESSION['cart'])
```

Comment: This works perfectly - thanks!

I tried this before, but for some reason I used something like:
count($_SESSION['cart']['sessID'])
so I got the number of items in each array, rather than the number of arrays in the Session.

Thanks again - I appreciate it

Answer (score 5):

If you are sure `$_SESSION['cart']` contains something, you can use:

```
$items_in_cart = count($_SESSION['cart'])
```

If it can be empty:

```
$items_in_cart = is_array($_SESSION['cart']) ? count($_SESSION['cart']) : 0
```

Comment: This is correct but you should change the variable name to something other than $items_in_cart, because the content is the number of $sessID in cart. For the number of items you had to sum up the quantities.